# lex program to count number of odd integers in a file separated by space

Tags: lex, compiler-construction

```
%{
int count=0;
%}
%%
[0-9]*[1|3|5|7|9]|[0-9]*[" "][1|3|5|7|9] {count ++;}
.+ {}
%%
int main(){
yyin=fopen("abc.txt","r");
yylex();
printf("no are %d",count);
return 0;
}
```

contents of file are:-

1. 15311
2. 2
3. 15 21
4. 2

the answer should be three ie 15311,15 and 21.
how to do?

Comment: `[1|3]` and `[" "]` do not do what you think they do. Please reread the [flex manual section on patterns](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns), or consult a good book on regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The most fool-proof approach here is not to try to make regular expressions recognize odd integers, but rather to recognize integers, and then test the last digit of `yytext`.

```
[0-9]+ {
   /* insert slick trick here exploiting ASCII digit representation */
   switch (yytext[yyleng-1]) {
   case '1': '3': '5': '7': '9':
     count++;
     break;
   }
}
```

For instance, if we do the naive thing and just extract digit sequences ending in an odd digit, like this:

```
[0-9]*[13579] { ... }
```

we run into the problem that given an input like `1234`, the above extracts the token `123` and leaves the `4` in the input stream!  This `4` then falls victim to the `.+` rule that eats everything else.

To do this with regular expressions, we basically have to have two rules: one which recognizes odd decimal number and one which recognizes even ones. These must be mutually exclusive:

```
[0-9]*[13579] { count++; }
[0-9]*[02468] { }
```

Also, the catch-all rule is completely wrong. It must not be `.+`!  The problem with `.+` is that suppose the input is this `JUNK1234`. Well, this doesn't match the rule for a number, so it falls down to `.+`. But, oops, `.+` eats the whole darn thing, including the `1234`. Maybe we wanted to just skip the `JUNK` and recognize the `1234`?

As a rule of thumb, a catch-all rule in a lexer which tries to recover in the case of no match should consume only one character:

```
. {}
```

Note that in Lex, `.` doesn't match newlines. So to skip over newlines too, we better make that:

```
(.|\n) {}
```

Otherwise the newlines won't match our rule, and instead will fall victim to Lex's own default rule, which matches one character and prints it. The program will echo all the newlines in the input.

Answer (score 0):

`.+` matches a complete line. If that line contains several numbers, flex will choose the `.+` rule, because of the maximal munch rule. As your file is written, the `.+` rule will also be used for lines containing one number because your other pattern matches an odd number followed by a space followed by an odd digit, plus some other things as a result of your putting `|` and `"` inside the character classes, where they act as ordinary characters.

So fix your pattern for odd numbers and change the fallback pattern from `.+` to `.|\n` so that it only matches one character. (The newline is needed because in flex the wildcard pattern `.` does not match a newline). See rhe [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns) for details.

If you want to see what flex is doing, use the `-d` debugging option when you use flex to create your scanner. That will trace every pattern match; it is also described in the flex manual in the debugging options section.